# FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting this error while defining the class below:

---

```
    public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment
    implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
```

---

I'm using eclipse. I've added jars - android-support-v13.jar and android-support-v4.jar in the build path but still I'm getting the error. Please let me know what I'm missing here.

Thanks

Comment: Is that the proper, fully qualified name for that type? Were you supposed to have an `import` statement for it?

Comment: import statement is present "import android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat;"

Comment: What is the error you are getting just post the line or your java class.

Comment: I was able to fix this error. This error got fixed after installing the latest version (23.2.0) of android-support-v13.jar from Android SDK Manager.. Thanks